# Refresh listview setvisible all checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

EDIT: I wish show all checkbox with a longitemclick. But only get show one checkbox

I have a listview with my custom row.xml. Row.xml has a checkbox, imageview, textview and an imageview.

By default, the checkbox is visibility:GONE in the row.xml

In the code, I override the next method:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    checkBox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

But only get one row visible. I tried everything with the code, but i can´t find the solution. Any idea?

Kisses ^^

EDIT with my custom_row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:checked="false"

        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/text1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your xml ? I think that you have set wrap_content as hight

Comment: To which view are you registering the context menu? The entire ListView or a single row?

Comment: I don't understand the reason for overriding the context menu method but you can simply set them to `visible` in the `getView()` method according to some flag or whatever it is you are using.

Comment: Edit:
I don´t kwon very well what i am doing. I´m newbie. I only want that when I have a longitemclick appears the check box in all listview like in a file explorer and delete, rename, share, etc. Thak´s guys for yours answer. Kisses ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can´t find an efficient solution. Finally i build two custom_row.xml and two class mycustom_arrayadapter

The first class mycustom_arrayadapter gets custom_row with checkbox.visibility(GONE) and the second mycustom_arrayadapter gets  custom_row with visibility.VISIBLE(when i make a longclick in the listview)

It works, but I think it´s a worst solution ;(

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your adapter setCheckboxVisibility(boolean isVisible). And use it to set the visibility you want.

```
private int checkboxVisibility = View.GONE;

public void setCheckboxVisibility(int visibility) {
    this.checkboxVisibility = visibility
}
```

Then use the checkboxVisibility attribute in the getView() method of you adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    checkbox.setVisibility(checkboxVisibility);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Elodie Ferrais, I´m going to try this. Kisses ^^

Answer (score -1):

visibility:gone acts like the view never existed. You should use visibility:invisible in the xml so that you can later make it visible from the code.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE

Comment: No, that is not correct. It doesn't mean it never existed, there just isn't a space cleared out for it. It doesn't mean it can't be changed to `visible`

Comment: Thanks to point it out. I should rephrase it: "as if the view had not been added."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility

Comment: if a use invisible appears a gap in the space of checkbox. I use gone better ^^